# "java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object" when runs JNI program

Tags: java, java-native-interface, hdfs, scribe

I am so pain for installing scribe & hdfs. worth to appreciate, I solved most of the problems. However, I am stuck here.

I install libhdfs , and I write a "Hello world" test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "hdfs.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    string host = "10.210.74.143";
    int port = 9000;
    hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect(host.c_str(),port);
    return 0;
}
```

It print this msg when I run it:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I swear I have set the CLASSPATH

Comment: usually when I have seen can't find java/lang/Object it means it cannot find the Java Runtime Environment (aka the JVM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are running a C program instead of using a dynamic library from a Java Program. Is that really what you intended to do?

If so, maybe you need to explicitly create a JVM (interesting):
See http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html unless hdfsConnect function does it for you.

Comment: hdfsConnect will create a JVM for me . I solve the problem , libhdfs get the jars in a certain path , not the CLASSPATH , I do not know the reason.

Comment: I copied the code you gave in    http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html  

then compile it :  
gcc -o hello hello.c -I /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/include/linux -L /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm  

but when I run ./hello , it prints :
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: /usr/libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @renenglish, so they look for jars in a certain path, huh? bummer. As for not finding libjava.so, I think the JAVA_HOME might not have been set up properly. On windows the library (java.dll) would be under JAVA_HOME\bin

Comment: Well the library java.dll (or libjava.lib) seems to be part of the JRE and not the JDK. Not sure if that matters though.

Comment: Now I solved the problem , I copied libjvm.so to /usr/lib64 , when I linked with it , then here is the problem : it can not find the libs it depends on. The correct method is linking with the libjvm.so in $JAVA_HOME( for me  is :/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so) using -Wl,-rpath